# Multitangent to a polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, polynomials

I'm trying to build some exercises on tangents of functions for beginner students in mathematical analysis. In particular I would like to suggest the study of polynomial functions  $ y = p (x) $ of which is possible to determine the graph with elementary methods and also determine (if it exists) the  $n$-tangent, i.e. a straight line $ y = mx + q $ (with $ m \ne 0$  to avoid trivial solutions) which has $ n $ distinct points of tangency with the graph and no other intersection points with it, so that the system
$$
\begin{cases}
y=p(x)\\
y=mx+q
\end{cases}
$$ 
has $n$ double solutions.

For bi-tangents I find, for example, functions of the form:
$$
y= a(x^4-3k^2x^2+2k^3x)
$$
that have as bi-tangents the straight lines 
$$
y=2ak^3x-\dfrac{9}{4}ak^3
$$
or:
$$
y=a\left( \dfrac{1}{4}x^4 -\dfrac{3k}{2}x^3+\dfrac{9k^2}{4}x^2-k^3x\right)
$$
with bi-tangents  $y=ak^3x$.

I cannot, however, find an example with a $ 3 $ -tangent, i.e. a polynomial of sixth degree $ y = p (x) $ such that $ p (x) $ and $ p '(x) $ are decomposable (more or less easily) in factors of degree  $n \le 2$, and that at the same time has a $3$-tangent such that hits points of tangency can be determined without using  the general formula to solve a cubic equation.
Someone knows any function of this type, or may suggest an efficient way to find it?

In other words: find a function:
$$
y=a_6x^6+a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0
$$
such that $ y $ and $y'$ are factorizable with factors of degree $n \le 2$ and there exist $m,q \in \mathbb{R}$ (or better $\in \mathbb{Q}$) such that
$$
a_6x^6+a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+(a_1-m)x+a_0-q
 =a_6\left( x^3+Bx^2+Cx+D\right)^2
$$ 
and the latter $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial is also factorizable.

---

Added after the Answer.

The answer of Michael Burr don't fit the request  that $f(x)$ and $f′(x)$ has roots that we can find solving equations of degree $\le 2$.

Here I sum up and a bit generalize the problem:

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $2n > 4$ and $f'(x) $ its derivative. I want determine the coefficients of $f(x)$ in such a way that:

all the real roots of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ can be found solving equations of degree $\le 2$, and there are $m,q \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the polynomial $g(x)=f(x)+mx+q$ has $n$ double roots.

Or proof that such a polynomial can not exists.

Comment: Assuming that we fix the scale by $a_6=1$ it follows that the required $B,C,D, m,q$ exist if and only if
$$64a_2=5a_5^4-24a_5^2a_4+16a_4^2+32a_5a_3.$$ Undoubtedly you knew this, and it is not clear if this helps. Bringing it up just in case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you. I've found other similar equations fixing the value of $m$ or of some roots of the initial polynomial and of his derivative, but all seems to translate the problem to the solution of a high degree ($>2$) equation of the remaining coefficients that cannot be solved (in general) with elementary methods. So my doubt is that a polynomial with the needed properties does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

After three solutions, I found the easy way!

Start with $g(x)=(x-p)^2(x-r)^2(x-s)^2$.

For any $m$ and $q$, consider $y=m(x-p)+q$.  Add this to $g$, to get $f$, then $f$ passes through $(p,q)$ and the line $y=m(x-p)+q$ is tangent to the curve of $f$ at $p$, $r$, and $s$.

Comment: Yes, this give a three-tangent, but my problem is more subtle. I want also that $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ be factorizable with factors of degree $\le 2$. In general we can always find a multi tangent starting from a polynomial with $n$ double roots and applying a coordinates transformation that give a new $x-$axis (as in your solution) but the new function has no more ''simple'' roots. If we want that also his derivative has simple roots (so to find the graph in an elementary way) the problem become more difficult ( and I not know if there is a solution).